# Prevent or Listen for a user removing event listeners in developer tools?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-devtools, event-listener

How can I prevent or listen for a user removing event listeners in developer tools?

Is this possible?

[image: Sample Removal via Developer Tools]

In the example above, when a user removes an "Event Listener", I would like to act upon the action.  Is there an event listener for event listeners?

Comment: You can re-add the listener in setInterval.

Comment: I don't want to re-add it. What i want is to display alert message when i remove event listener from dev tools

Comment: The only approach I can think of is intercepting `EventTarget.removeEventListener`. One way is shown here: https://gist.github.com/alessioalex/fc536ef87713d0a9ed89

Comment: `delete EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const removeEventListenerOriginal = EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener;
const p = document.querySelector("p");
const onClick = e => console.log("clicked", e.target.tagName);


EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener = function(...args) {
  const [eventType, handler, capture] = args;

  console.log(`Event Listener Removed For`, this, {
    eventType,
    handler,
    capture
  });

  // your logic here

  // call the original function or not. its up to you
  removeEventListenerOriginal.call(this, ...args);
  // or removeEventListenerOriginal.apply(this, args);
}

p.addEventListener("click", onClick);
// try removing the event from dev console
```

```html
<p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo</p>
```