# Listen for "event removal" in JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a very large application with a lot of JavaScript. I am trying to determine how I can find the location where a click event is being removed from a specific element.

There is a simple event listener on a specific field added via jQuery (this is an example).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#id-name').on('click', function(e) {
        window.alert('hello');
    });

});
```

If break execution right after this and examine the element in Chrome Inspector, I see the event attached to the element. However, once I continue execution and the page finishes loading, the element no longer has the event. Something is removing it, but I can't find out where this is happening.

Is there a way to listen for "event removal" and trigger code then, so that I can identify where and how this is getting removed? Any other suggestions in locating where the click event is being removed?

Comment: Can you [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64162958), and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could override the removeEventListener method and trace it back to see what's calling it.

```
window.removeEventListener = (type, listener, useCapture)=>console.trace(type, listener, useCapture)
```